# How to start @scheduled cron only when method is explicitly called?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cron, spring-scheduled

By default, @Scheduled starts automatically at runtime even without explicitly calling the method.

I want to be able to only start the cron timer only whenever I explicitly call the method, hence can be seen in my code:

```
    @GetMapping("/checkstatus")
    public void getExistingTransaction(@RequestBody String uniq_id){
    //get Existing Transaction using uniq_id:
        //cases: uniq_id found, uniq_id not found:
    //if uniq_id is found: Find Transaction by uniq_id
    if(transactionRepository.findByUniqueId(uniq_id) != null){
        //if uniq id exists and found: perform checking cron:
        testCron(); //<-- this is the cron method.
    }
}
```

This is the implementation of the Cron method:

```
    //helper:
@Scheduled(cron = "*/10 * * * * *")
private void testCron() {
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
    logger.info("Transaction exists and cron stuff workz" + currentTime);
}
```

My question is: **How can I control its execution and how can I stop it whenever a business logic has been satisfied?**

Comment: What's your requirement? Can't use java executors?

Comment: The only requirement I see is that we should use cron expressions(ex. whenever the method is called, call testCron every 30 seconds until a business logic inside that method has been satisfied).

Comment: We have addressed this using Quartz cron jobs with Spring if you are interested. or you could go with Spring TaskExecutors  java concurrency)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36267127/how-to-start-scheduled-jobs-dynamically-with-spring-and-quartz might help if you are willing to use Quartz with Spring

Answer (score 0):

You may use `started` flag:

```
private boolean started = false;

private void startCron() {
    started = true;
}

private void stopCron() {
    started = false;
}

@Scheduled(cron = "*/10 * * * * *")
private void testCron() {
    if (!started) {
        return;
    }
    //...
}
```